# Different behaviour of grep with pipe from nc on alpine vs ubuntu

Tags: grep, pipe, minecraft, alpine-linux

I want to check if a Minecraft server is reachable. This is used as a health check for docker. On Ubuntu all is fine, on alpine linux not.

This requesting the status string in json from a public server:

```
echo -e "\x16\x00\x04\x10\x6d\x63\x2e\x65\x6c\x64\x65\x72\x63\x72\x61\x66\x74\x2e\x64\x65\x63\xdd\x01\x01\x00" | nc mc.eldercraft.de 25565
```

Because you maybe want to know what you are testing, the request contains of:

1. 22 content byte after this
2. protocol version bytes 00, 04
3. 16 hostname bytes after this
4. 2 port bytes
5. end of handshake byte
6. 1 content byte after this
7. give me status byte

If successful the return contains amount of players, so I want to check if its in.

```
echo -e "\x16\x00\x04\x10\x6d\x63\x2e\x65\x6c\x64\x65\x72\x63\x72\x61\x66\x74\x2e\x64\x65\x63\xdd\x01\x01\x00" | nc mc.eldercraft.de 25565 | grep -q '"players":' && echo "ok"
```

- On Ubuntu 16.04 lts, "ok"
- On Alpine 3.9 in docker, grep error (no output, return 1)

*Question:*
Why doesn't process grep this output on alpine and ubuntu like the same? Even if I store the value in a variable and echo this to grep it can't process this string. Even if I just grep for 'players'.

**See answer for explanation**

*Solutions:*

- grep -F ..., only exact match

  echo "$bin" | grep -Fq 'players' && echo ok
- or convert nc binary output to text

  echo "$bin" | od -c -A n | tr -d '\n ' | grep -q 'players' && echo ok

Comment: Have you tried installing `grep` package on Alpine, which is GNU grep?

Comment: Done, no match.

Comment: How about trying with `bash` on Alpine, instead of the default `ash`? Perhaps the shell has some subtle impact.

Comment: alpine + /bin/bash, there its working

Comment: grep -Fq 'players' is working on alpine sh, can it be that the output of nc is something like binary which isn't processed by sh same as bash?

Comment: Nice! I'm not familiar with `nc`, honestly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, for me this helped a lot and I now have a workaround for my problem.
I will still keep this question open, because I can't answer my question "whats exactly happening and why".

Comment: Sure! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate the results on an Alpine 3.9 Docker with the different shell/grep variations, exiting and starting a new container for each test, then double checked.

Here's what I've got:

- Alpine 3.9, ash, BusyBox grep: not OK.
- Alpine 3.9, bash, BusyBox grep: not OK.
- Alpine 3.9, ash, GNU grep: OK.
- Alpine 3.9, bash, GNU grep: OK.
- Alpine 3.9, ash, BusyBox `grep -F`: OK.

So it seems that grep is indeed the root cause of the difference, and the way it handles the binary output from nc.

With Alpine 3.9 and GNU grep, if we omit the `-q` and echo, we'll get the following output:

> Binary file (standard input) matches

This could suggest that GNU and BusyBox grep may handle binary files differently.

Browsing through BusyBox's grep, https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/findutils/grep.c, we can find the following comments, under grep's options listing:

```
/* ignored: -a "assume all files to be text" */
/* ignored: -I "assume binary files have no matches" */
```

So carefully estimating, BusyBox grep will always give zero results for binary data (with the default options) - that well explains the behavior.

With `-F` - "fgrep mode", BusyBox grep will match `"players":` literally to the binary characters stream, so this works.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like I did something wrong, because ubuntu bash + busybox grep did work for me and ash + gnu grep not. Anyway, added a solution to convert binary to text with busybox.